# java.io.FileNotFoundException-- File not found

Tags: java

I am trying to write a function that would copy code from a source file to destination file.

`copyCode("D:/rraina_IN-L0124_173"+fileName.substring(1), oldTempFile);`

This is my function call.

`String oldTempFile = "D:/rraina_IN-L0124_173/temp/Old_" + fileName;`

this is `oldTempFile` that is the destination.

This is the function.

```
private static void copyCode(String src, String destination) throws IOException {
        FileChannel src1 = new FileInputStream(new File(src)).getChannel();
        FileChannel dest1 = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination)).getChannel();
        dest1.transferFrom(src1, 0, src1.size());
        src1.close();
        dest1.close();
    }
```

However when I run it I get the error :

> Failed for
>   file:/gatherer/gather/main/scripts/HartfordRetirement.javajava.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\rraina_IN-L0124_173\temp\Old_HartfordRetirement.java (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)

Comment: check for the file with name Old_HartfordRetirement.java  is present in directory D:\rraina_IN-L0124_173\temp\?? check for spell of file name

Answer (score 1):

Check for present of the file as,

```
File file = new File(destination);
boolean isFileExists = file.exists();
System.out.println(isFileExists);  // this should return true if the file is present
```

check for the file with name Old_HartfordRetirement.java is present in directory D:\rraina_IN-L0124_173\temp\ check for spell of file name

Answer (score 0):

You should check existance of folders that you want to work with them and source file.
use this code:

```
private static void copyCode(String src, String destination) throws IOException {
    File srcFile = new File(src);

    if (srcFile.exist()) {
        File destFile = new File(destination);
        File destFileParent = destFile.getParentFile();
        if (!destFileParent.exist()) destFileParent.mkdirs();

        FileChannel src1 = new FileInputStream(srcFile).getChannel();
        FileChannel dest1 = new FileOutputStream(destFile)).getChannel();
        dest1.transferFrom(src1, 0, src1.size());
        src1.close();
        dest1.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method invocation, the source argument is missing one file seperator.

```
copyCode("D:/rraina_IN-L0124_173/"+fileName.substring(1), oldTempFile);
```

Also I would suggest to check that the value of fileName.substring(1) is returning the correct file name.